# What is this white stuff on my succulent’s leaves?

Tags: succulents, fungus

I noticed this stuff on my succulents after a watering. They are indoors by a south facing window so they get plenty of light per day. I’ve included two close up pictures of the affected areas. I don’t see any movement so I don’t think it’s insect related.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot tell from the picture if that is a natural thing that some succulent plants have (hairs or waxy coatings on parts of the plants) or if that is something new.  Do you have a way of looking more closely with a magnification lens or by taking a picture with your camera on macro zoom and increasing the magnification?  I'm wondering if it could be a seasonal change but I am not familiar with that particular succulent to know.

Answer (score 1):

It might be white mold, a.k.a powdery mildew, it may depend on how much you water it. Make sure that the soil completely dries before watering it again.

If the plant is getting too much water, the leaves may get soft, soggy an may even produce white mold.

Let the soil dry out and leave it dry for a few days to a week and the mold should die after a while. Or, you can cut the affected part off of the plant. I had this same problem with my Aloe Vera plant!

One thing you can do is to mix 1 tbs of baking soda with 1/2 tsp of liquid soap (with no detergent) and one gallon of water. If you want make just a little bit, portion them all to be 1/4 of the ingredients (1/4 tbs baking soda, 1/8 tsp soap, 1 quart water). Mix and lightly cover the affected area with this mixture.

Hope this helps you :)